# Is it okay to modify the GitHub Gist embed code?

Tags: github

I'm using Gist to display code bits on my blog (or rather, will be if/when this question is answered) so that I can use its nice syntax highlighting. When I embed a Gist on my page, it has a bar beneath the embedded and nicely formatted code that looks like this:

[image]

Now, I decided this bar looks kind of ugly if I have several lines of snippets that are only one line long, with this bar underneath each of them. I discovered that can easily hide this bar with CSS, but I want to find out if it's 'okay' to do this. Are there any legal repercussions I should be aware of? I skimmed Github's terms of service and spent a few minutes Googling this but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Seems like that should be completely fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't need to modifiy the [gist/embed.css](https://gist.github.com/stylesheets/gist/embed.css) from GitHub, but you could simply add a more specific rule (as [described here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32236-hide-horizontal-scrollbars/)) which would be declared *after* the existing one:

```
.gist .gist-file .gist-meta {
  overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden;
}
.gist .gist-file .gist-data {
  overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If this is declared after the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gist.github.com/stylesheets/gist/embed.css"/>`, it should take precedence.
See also this example of CSS modification when making a [Embedding a Gist in Your WordPress Blog](http://arin.me/blog/embed-a-gist-in-your-wordpress-blog).

Comment: That's what I meant, although I what I ended up doing was setting `.gist-meta {display:none;}` and `.gist .gist-file {border-bottom: 0px}` to get rid of the bottom border. I guess I should have been more specific; I was actually referring to the bar that says "This Gist brought to you by GitHub..." on it.